# Set Custom value in checkbox

Tags: forms

I have an array...

```
    $my_array = array(1 => 'Value One', 2 => 'Value Two',3 => 'Value Three');
```

In Form API, I want to create checkbox for each value.

```
    foreach($my_array as $key => $value) {
      $form['custom_field'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#title' => $value,
        '#default_value' => variable_get('custom_field'),
      );
    }
```

by default is stores in value, '0' or '1'.
It should actuly be saving the $key as value.

I know this can be done simply using 'type' as 'checkboxes' but actuly I need to goroup it each time each check box with a text field.

```
    foreach($my_array as $key => $value) {
      $form['custom_field'.$key] = array(
          '#type' => 'checkbox',
          '#title' => $value,
          '#default_value' => variable_get('custom_field'),
        );
        $form['custom_field'.$key] = array(
          '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#title' => 'Limit',
          '#size' => 10,
          '#maxlength' => 10,
          '#default_value' => variable_get('limit_variable'),
          '#required' => TRUE,
        );
      }
```

`
Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding '#return_value':

```
foreach($my_array as $key => $value) {
      $form['custom_field'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#return_value' => $key,
        '#title' => $value,
        '#default_value' => variable_get('custom_field'),
      );
    }
```

Comment: @Tanvir if it worked, why don't you mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fieldset](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#fieldset) to group fields together. You cannot use same key for two form elements since they override existing. So, changed checkbox key value to **'custom_field_checkbox_'.$key** and text field to **'custom_field_text_'.$key**

```
foreach($my_array as $key => $value) {
        $form['custom_field_group_'.$key] = array(
          '#type' => 'fieldset',
          '#title' => t('Contact settings'), 
          '#collapsible' => TRUE, 
          '#collapsed' => FALSE,
        );
        $form['custom_field_group_'.$key]['custom_field_checkbox_'.$key] = array(
          '#type' => 'checkbox',
          '#title' => $value,
          '#return_value' => $key,
          '#default_value' => variable_get('custom_field'),
        );
        $form['custom_field_group_'.$key]['custom_field_text_'.$key] = array(
          '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#title' => 'Limit',
          '#size' => 10,
          '#maxlength' => 10,
          '#default_value' => variable_get('limit_variable'),
          '#required' => TRUE,
        );
      }
```

Comment: Thanks Anil, fieldName is just a typo. But I should have take care of that even if I am just posting to query something.

Comment: Still, I am not getting what I need. Solution you suggested will still save 'checkbox' as 1 or 0. e-g <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="1" name="custom_field_checkbox_5" id="edit-custom-field-checkbox-5"> - You see here is value=1, but it should be the key of the value.

Comment: Updated answer...